# Using "&" when passing function to action hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I have noticed some WordPress plugin classes pass the class method to a hook using the ampersand prefix.

for example:

```
add_action( 'somehook', array( &$this, 'some_function' ) );
```

Is there a specific reason to do so?

I understand the `&` makes it pass a reference instead of an instance but most of the time I see it used that seems irrelevant as it is a method and not an object.

Is there a particular reason to do it this way with wordpress action hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a fallback for PHP4 where objects are passed by values.

Since WordPress [requires PHP5.2.4](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress) at least, there're no reasons to use `&` prefix anymore.

Comment: Yup this is the right answer, the code just hasn't been updated (it works, why fiddle with it?)

Comment: It actually doesn't *require* PHP >= 5.6, it just [recommends it](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/). However I highly doubt it would work with PHP 4.

Comment: @Mike It is 5.2.4 :)